# inserting value in postgres custom-built type field using java api

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a type as 'designation' in my postgreSQL DB instance. 
I have a table named 'Prof' that has a column 'designation' of type 'designation'.
I want to insert values into this column using java.

code snippet:

```
insProf.setInt(1, id);
insProf.setInt(2, univ_id);
insProf.setString(3, desg);
int rs_insProf = insProf.executeUpdate();
```

output error:

```
Enter designation: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input value for enum designation: ""
```

Please help with with syntax, I am not able to figure out how best I can handle this.

Comment: how your query look like?

Comment: I would try to use `insProf.setObject(3, desg, Types.OTHER)`

Comment: Are you sure that your `designation` type accepts the empty string `''`? (It only accepts it, if you *enumerated* that too within the definition). You may want to use `NULL` instead of the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use setObject() and getObject() method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,%20java.lang.Object)

take a look at the setObject() and getObject().

according to the documentation, "If the object is of a class implementing the interface SQLData, the JDBC driver should call the method SQLData.writeSQL to write it to the SQL data stream."

so you can create your own type by creating a custom class implementing SQLData interface.

plus, don't forget to register your custom type into the driver's type map.

there is a tutorial too: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlcustommapping.html

Answer (score 0):

To insert an enum, you have to use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Prof (id, unit_id, designation) VALUES(?, ?, {?, ?, ?});
//-------------------------------------------------------^-------^
```

Or

You can use an array in your case of type designation like this :

```
INSERT INTO Prof (id, unit_id, designation) VALUES(?, ?, ARRAY[?]::designation[]);
//-------------------------------------------------------------^
```

---

To set multiple you can use a loop for example to fill your enum, if you have more then one enum.